# Create an SQL script to find a simple product name with its configurable product SKU In Magento 2 [Magento 2]

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, magento2.3, database, query

Create an SQL script to find a simple product name with its configurable product SKU In Magento 2 [Magento 2]

Anyone with a better solution than my one are appreciated.

Please share your answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Query as follows:***

```
select
 nametable.value as product_name,
 parent.type_id as parent_product_type, parent.sku as parent_sk,
 child.type_id as child_product_type, child.sku child_sku
from catalog_product_entity as parent
join catalog_product_relation as link
    on link.parent_id = parent.entity_id
join catalog_product_entity as child
    on child.entity_id = link.child_id
join catalog_product_entity_varchar as nametable ON nametable.row_id = parent.entity_id
AND nametable.store_id = 0
AND nametable.attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id
  FROM eav_attribute
  WHERE attribute_code = 'name'
    AND entity_type_id =
      (SELECT entity_type_id
       FROM eav_entity_type
       WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
where parent.sku = 'product-sku'
```

If my answer helped you, you can accept the answer so it can help others also.

Comment: Sorry but this answer accepts only  asking answer..

Comment: @MohitPatel can you post a more optimize solution if possible?

Comment: you means one answer ??

Comment: @MohitPatel optimize answer for Magento Enterprise Edition [2.3.3]

Answer (score 0):

Optimized for Magento Commerce 2.3.3 ( formerly Enterprise Edition)  - The parent uses row_id instead of entity_id. Also, removed store_id as it's unnecessary if you have one store and potentially wrong if you have multi store.

```
SELECT
  nametable.value child_name,
  parent.type_id parent_product_type,
  parent.sku parent_sku,
  child.type_id child_product_type,
  child.sku child_sku
FROM
  catalog_product_entity parent
  JOIN catalog_product_relation link
    ON link.parent_id = parent.row_id
  JOIN catalog_product_entity child
    ON child.entity_id = link.child_id
  JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar nametable
    ON nametable.row_id = parent.row_id
    AND nametable.attribute_id =
    (SELECT
      attribute_id
    FROM
      eav_attribute
    WHERE attribute_code = 'name'
      AND entity_type_id =
      (SELECT
        entity_type_id
      FROM
        eav_entity_type
      WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
WHERE parent.sku = 'YOUR-SKU';
```